# How can I customize material-ui V1 components across entire application when creating a theme?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

in material-ui v0, when creating a theme with `const muiThemeV0 = getMuiTheme(theme);`
i can simply add a property to the themeOptions for each component based on this file:
https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/src/styles/getMuiTheme.js (currently on the master branch when writing this question), and can customize not only colors but the theme border-radius etc, and specific components sizes and colors.
for example:

```
const theme = {
  slider: {
    selectionColor:  colors.primary1Color,
    handleFillColor: colors.primary1Color,
    trackSize:       6,
  }
}
```

I tried going through the https://material-ui-next.com/customization/overrides/ docs, but can't see examples and/or a list of options in the source code like MUI-v0 when i want to use `const muiThemeV1 = createMuiTheme(theme);`
are there any docs for this kind of customization in v1?
is this even possible?

Comment: [This example looks straightforward](https://codesandbox.io/s/9vloq69q4)

Comment: this example doesnt use the `createMuiTheme`

Comment: [Maybe this one](https://material-ui-next.com/customization/themes/)

Comment: thanks @Tico , i guess their docs are still not fully ready

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In v1, you can use the theme `overrides` property to customize the styles of a specific component type. Instead of providing theme options for individual components, this feature allows you to customize every style that material-ui injects into the DOM.

You can find a list of the CSS classes for each component on the website (in component API section).

The following example customizes the appearance of the Button component

```js
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  overrides: {
    MuiButton: {
      // override root styles for the button component.
      root: {
        // Name of the rule
        background: 'linear-gradient(45deg, #FE6B8B 30%, #FF8E53 90%)',
        borderRadius: 3,
        color: 'white',
        height: 48,
        padding: '0 30px',
        marginRight: 32,
      },
      // Custom styles for the raised button variant
      raised: {
        borderRadius: 50,
        color: 'white',
        // Custom hover styles for raised button 
        '&:hover': {
          boxShadow: shadows[4],
        },
        // Custom active styles for raised button
        '&:active': {
          boxShadow: `${shadows[24]} !important`,
        },
      },
    },
  }
});
```

[Live example on code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/jnw98onlnv?module=%2Fdemo.js)

[Documentation on theme overrides](https://material-ui-next.com/customization/themes/#customizing-all-instances-of-a-component-type)

Comment: Thank Luke! thats exactly what i looked for.